Flutter local_auth and shuftripro_onsite_sdk conflict in project back button
I am using local_auth package for fingerprint and face verification and shuftripro_onsite_sdk package for verification document and face in my flutter project.
local_auth package recommended that FlutterActivity change to FlutterFragmentactivity in MainActivity.kt file. When I use these two package then Android version over 12 back button and Popscope method is not working.
If I use FlutterFragmentActivity that time shuftipro_onsite_sdk is not working and if I remove it then my app is not work its give me runtime exception that is platform exception.
Is there any solution to use instead FlutterFragmentActivity and working with local_auth package or how can I solve this problem?
Main.kt file
app label build_gradle
applabel gradle
android label gradle
pubspec.yml
I am trying to solve this with local_auth and shuftipro_onsite_sdk with backbutton. Need to FlutterFragmentActivity working to compitibale with FlutterActivity with these plugins.

This solution works for me: Android Back Button closes my Flutter app
bool _defaultOnNavigationNotification(NavigationNotification _) {
  switch (WidgetsBinding.instance.lifecycleState) {
    case null:
    case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    // Avoid updating the engine when the app isn't ready.
      return true;
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
    case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      SystemNavigator.setFrameworkHandlesBack(true); /// This must be `true` instead of `notification.canHandlePop`, otherwise application closes on back gesture.
      return true;
  }
}

And then:
MaterialApp.router(
  onNavigationNotification: _defaultOnNavigationNotification,
);


Got it but I use another way. I change in kotlin file. And right now its working fine.
